# Возвращение всего словаря из map, а не только его ключей

Tags: python, map, словари

Есть задача из списка словарей, например:

```
chunks = [{
    "start_time": 131599790828677667,
    "end_time": 131602301828449657,
    "type": "StreamVideoEnc",
    "codec": "H264",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 464,
    "size_of_data": 5527561988,
    "num_of_frames": 4870290,
    "recording_id": 0
},
{
    "start_time": 131602414780830188,
    "end_time": 131602437126776507,
    "type": "StreamVideoEnc",
    "codec": "H264",
    "width": 1600,
    "height": 1200,
    "size_of_data": 375680337,
    "num_of_frames": 44551,
    "recording_id": 4
}]
```

Сформировать словарь вида:

```
{
    "start_time": 131599790828677667,
    "end_time": 131602301828449657,
},
{
    "start_time": 131602414780830188,
    "end_time": 131602437126776507,
}
```

Решил использовать map.

Где делаю следующее:

```
dict(map(
    lambda chunk: {
         "start_time": chunk['start_time'],
         "end_time": chunk['end_time'],
    }
    chunks
))
```

в результате выполнения получаю словарь:

```
{'start_time: 'end_time'}
```

Подскажите как корректно в таком случае получить нужный словарь?

Comment: может заменить `dict(map(` на `list(map(` (ну и добавить запятую между `lambda ...` и `chunks`)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы оставить только указанные ключи в списке словарей `list_of_dicts`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

keys = 'start_time', 'end_time'
get_values = itemgetter(*keys)
filtered_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, get_values(d))) for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Хотя для двух ключей можно для читаемости по месту их указать:

```
filtered_dicts = [{'start_time': d['start_time'], 'end_time': d['end_time']}
                  for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, сам бы я решал эту задачу так:

```
d = [{key: value for (key, value) in chunk.items()
      if key in ('start_time', 'end_time')
      }
     for chunk in chunks
     ]

print(d)
```